# IE10 is not adding Origin Header for CORS requests to domain with same host path but different port #

Tags: api, http-headers, cross-domain, cors, self-hosting

This is driving me absolutely nuts. I've hacked up a basic implementation of a self-hosted WebAPI server and MVC4 client. They're in separate solutions and set to run on different ports. CORS requests were working fine in the browsers that I got around to testing (IE10/FF/Chrome) the other day, but now suddenly IE10 has stopped adding the Origin header to the requests. I'm now experiencing this on my home computer in this dinky example, as well as in the implementation that I'm working on at work.

I've tried every combination I could think of in Google searches to see if someone else was experiencing this and had discovered a solution. The closest I came was this link to feedback on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/781303/origin-header-is-not-added-to-cors-requests-to-same-domain-but-different-port) that is still unresolved.

I've tried changing ports, making brand new projects, clearing browser cache; you name it, I've tried it (except for whatever ends up working, obviously!).

Here are the Request Headers for a Get request using Firefox:
Note: I had to add spaces for the Referer and Origin headers b/c of restriction to localhost in links

> Host: localhost:60000
>
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0
>
> Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
>
> Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>
> Referer: http:// localhost:50954/
>
> Origin: http:// localhost:50954
>
> Connection: keep-alive

Here are the Request Headers for the same Get request using IE10:

> Referer: http:// localhost:50954/
>
> Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
>
> Accept-Language: en-US
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)
>
> Connection: Keep-Alive
>
> DNT: 1
>
> Host: localhost:60000

The Origin header is left out in IE10 for other HTTP methods as well.

Here is the pertinent code for the sample MVC4 app:

Home/Index.cshtml:

```
@section scripts 
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#details').click(function () {
                $('#employee').empty();
                $.getJSON("http://localhost:60000/api/employees/12345", function (employee) {
                    var now = new Date();
                    var ts = now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes() + ':' + now.getSeconds();
                    var content = employee.Id + ' ' + employee.Name;
                    content = content + ' ' + employee.Department + ' ' + ts;
                    $('#employee').append($('<li/>', { text: content }));
                })
            });

            $('#update').click(function () {
                $('#employee').empty();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'PUT',
                    url: "http://localhost:60000/api/employees/12345",
                    data: { 'Name': 'Beansock', 'Department': 'Nucular Strategory' },
                    success: function (employee) {                        
                        var now = new Date();
                        var ts = now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes() + ':' + now.getSeconds();
                        var content = employee.Id + ' ' + employee.Name;
                        content = content + ' ' + employee.Department + ' ' + ts;
                        $('#employee').append($('<li/>', { text: content }));
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        console.log('Error:', error);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}

<div>
    <div>
        <h1>Employees Listing</h1>
        <input id="search" type="button" value="Get" />
        <input id="details" type="button" value="Details" />
        <input id="update" type="button" value="Update" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <ul id="employees"></ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <ul id="employee"></ul>
    </div>    
</div>
```

And here are the pertinent classes from the self-host WebAPI sample:

Program.cs

```
class Program
{
    private static readonly Uri Address = new Uri("http://localhost:60000");

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HttpSelfHostServer server = null;
        HttpSelfHostConfiguration config = null;

        // create new config
        config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(Address) { HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.Exact };

        // set up routing
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

        // set up handlers
        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new CorsHandler());

        // create server
        server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config);

        server.OpenAsync().Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("Server is up and running.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

EmployeesController.cs

```
public class EmployeesController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
    {   
        var employee = new Employee()
        {
            Id = id,
            Name = "Chucky Chucky Chuck",
            Department = "Profreshies"
        };

        var response = Request.CreateResponse<Employee>(HttpStatusCode.OK, employee);            

        return response;
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Put(Employee emp)
    {
        //employee2 = emp;
        var response = Request.CreateResponse<Employee>(HttpStatusCode.OK, emp);
        return response;
    }

    Employee employee2 = new Employee()
    {
        Id = 12345,
        Name = "Jimmy John John",
        Department = "Slow Lorisesssessss"
    };
}

internal class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
}
```

CorsHandler.cs

```
        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // if the request is coming from a browser supporting CORS
        if (request.Headers.Contains("Origin"))
        {
            // if the Request Origin does not match a server list of valid origins, or
            // if the Request Host does not match the name of this server (to help prevent DNS rebinding attacks)
            // return a 403 Forbidden Status Code
            var origin = request.Headers.GetValues("Origin").FirstOrDefault();
            var host = request.Headers.GetValues("Host").FirstOrDefault();
            if (validOrigins.Contains(origin) == false || !host.Equals(validHost))
                return Task<HttpResponseMessage>.Factory.StartNew(() => new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden));


            // if the Request is not a simple one, IE: POST, PUT, DELETE, then handle it through an OPTIONS Preflight
            if (request.Method == HttpMethod.Options)
            {
                var methodRequested = request.Headers.GetValues("Access-Control-Request-Method").FirstOrDefault();
                var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
                response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", methodRequested);

                return Task<HttpResponseMessage>.Factory.StartNew(() => response);
            }
            else // if Request is a GET or HEAD, or if it has otherwise passed the Preflight test, execute here
            {
                return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken)
                    .ContinueWith((task) =>
                    {
                        var response = task.Result;
                        response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);

                        return response;
                    });
            }
        }

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken)
                   .ContinueWith((task) => task.Result);
    }

    private IList<string> validOrigins = new List<string>() { "http://localhost:50954" };
    private string validHost = "localhost:60000";
}
```

I think that should be all you need to recreate the scenario. Is there something wrong with the code somewhere? Is IE10 not properly implementing the CORS spec by ignoring the port # when determining if it's a Cross-Origin Request? Does DoNotTrack defaulting to ENABLED have something to do with this? I could swear I had this working fine the other day... Any insight into this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance. BTW yes, I know I could be using async/await, except for the fact that I can't, because at work we're still on Windows Server 2003 >.<